# Reading InBox With Grails/Groovy?

Tags: spring, grails, groovy

DO I need to inject the JavaMail Objects into the application context and access my inbox the old fashion way or is there some "magic" in grails to handle it for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing that I know of, I recently used JavaMail in some test code and it's pretty painless using Groovy (once you get your head around the API)